# Chrome Extension: event listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am aware that because of Chrome's csp, I can't execute inline JavaScript. I have an html file called popup.html which contains this:

```
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="clickme">Button</a>
    </body>
```

and an external JavaScript file called chrome.js which contains this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init());

function init(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('clickme');
    elem.addEventListener('click',func());
}
function func(){
    alert('button clicked');
}
```

Whenever I reload the Chrome extension, or click the extension Icon, `func()` gets fired, but when I click the actual button that the listener is subscribed to (Button), nothing happens. I have looked at the debugger using "inspect popup" and using `location.reload()` in the console, it seems as though elem is correctly set via `getElementById()`, but the event is immediately fired upon reloading the page, instead of when the link is clicked.

How can I make the event fire on click instead of on pageload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a function to an event listener like this `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init());`

the function is immediately invoked.The correct way is to do this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: Yes, you are passing a function result after invoking it. Do as this answer suggests or put the function inline as anonymous.

Comment: where i find out event name?

Comment: [MDN Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events)

Comment: what if we had arguments in function ?